# Document Visibility works, but Sender can't see one of the documents

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using a composite template with Document Visibility enabled.

[image]

Signers are correctly excluded from documents they don't have tabs on, or can be explicitly excluded from those that no signer has tabs on with the `excludedDocuments` parameter.

**My problem is this**: the sender (me) cannot view one of the documents in the envelope that the sender is not a recipient of. According to docs:

> Recipients that have an administrative role (recipients with an Action
>   of Manage envelopes, Address recipients, Manage recipients, Receive a
>   copy or Acknowledge receipt) can always see all the documents in an
>   envelope, unless they are excluded when an envelope is sent. Documents
>   that do not have tags are always visible to all recipients, unless
>   they are excluded when an envelope is sent.

I tried adding the sender as a recipient of the document but received the error:

> Free form signing not allowed with document visibility

Which suggests I need to add a SignHereTab for the sender -- but there is nothing to sign, it should be for view only.

Partial request, includes the document in question. you can see how the sender is not a recipient on this document.

```
 {  
   "status":"sent",
   "compositeTemplates":[
      {  
       "inlineTemplates":[  
          {  
             "sequence":"0",
             "recipients":{  
                "signers":[  
                   {  
                      "name":"Harvey k",
                      "email":"somewhere",
                      "recipientId":1,
                      "accessCode":null,
                      "roleName":"Recipient",
                      "tabs":{  
                         "signHereTabs":[  
                            {  
                               "tabLabel":"borrowerSignHere\\*",
                               "documentId":2,
                               "recipientId":1,
                               "templateLocked":true,
                               "templateRequired":true,
                               "optional":false,
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   },
                   {  
                      "name":"first1 last1",
                      "email":"somewhere",
                      "recipientId":2,
                      "accessCode":null,
                      "roleName":"Signer",
                      "tabs":{  
                         "signHereTabs":[  
                            {  
                               "tabLabel":"agentSignHere\\*",
                               "documentId":2,
                               "recipientId":2,
                               "templateLocked":true,
                               "templateRequired":true,
                               "optional":false,
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      "excludedDocuments":[2,3,4,5,6]
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       ],
       "document":{  
          "name":"Agent Agreement",
          "documentId":2,
          "documentBase64":"...",
          "transformPdfFields":true
       }
    } // ... more templates documentId 2+ 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for using StackOverflow! Please remember to up-vote all useful answers, including answers to questions by others. And select/check the answer that best solves your own questions. You may also want to add your name or handle to your login record by clicking on your "user" name. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the sender a Carbon Copies Recipient with a routing order after the other recipients.

Comment: Aha! great idea -- I just tried this and the Sender can now see all documents, but DocuSign no longer asks the Sender to sign any of other documents in the Envelope -- I guess a recipient cannot be both CarbonCopy and Signer within the same envelope? Even though the recipient type is different within each Composite Template

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question. The sender is a signer, but only for some of the documents? And you want the sender to see all of the documents? In that case, you could add a signer name tab for the sender/signer to the other documents, but choose the color white so it won't show.

Comment: adding FullNameTab with documentId and pageNumber worked!!